# Update table column to 1 and the other rows to 0 at single action in LARAVEL 5.5

Tags: laravel

I'm quite new to laravel and I'm trying to update a record which I called STATUS. In my view blade I havel list of data with action button named "Set to default" What I want to accomplish is, once you click "set to default", the status(column) of that record will update to 1 and the rest of the rows should be updated to 0.

since I am new to this platform I really don't know what to do. But upon following some tuts out there I was able to create a BASIC CRUD with no other conditions.

here's my action button located in my **views\currencies\index.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::model($currency, ['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['currencies.update', $currency] ]) !!}<br/>
{!! Form::hidden('status', 1) !!}<br/>
{!! Form::submit('set default', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}<br/>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

[views\currencies\index.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipx6P.png)

to explain further. here's my update.blade.php. it updates the name and acronym in my "currencies" table.

```
<form action="{{ route('currencies.update', $currency) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="{{ $currency->status}}">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $currency->name }}"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="acronym" value="{{ $currency->acronym }}"><br/> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and currently here's my edit and update function in my CurrenciesController.

```
 public function edit(Currencies $currency)
    {
        return view('currencies.edit', compact('currency'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Currencies  $currencies
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Currencies $currency)
    {
        $currency->update($request->only('name','acronym','status'));
        return redirect()->route('currencies.index');
    }
```

it only captures the data from my add.blade and edit.blade.

now the button that displayed on **views\currencies\index.blade.php** which I also provided above should only update the status of the record.

What I want to achieve is once I click that button, it will pass the id to my currenciesController, then update the status from 0 to 1 and update the previous record which has '1' to '0'. the bottom line is there should be only one record which has a value of '1' in its status column.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Will you post the update method from the controller so that we can understand your progress.

Comment: Hi @ManoharKhadka apology for my luck of explanation. I just updated my question. thank you so much for your response!

Comment: You can go with @Ravi9994's answer if Currencies is your model name.

Comment: thank you also @ManoharKhadka! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is execute two queries,

one for update status 0 where status is 1

```
Currencies::where('status', 1)->update(['status' => 0]);
```

and other for change status 0 to 1 for the id you received

```
Currencies::where('id', $request->id)->update(['status' => 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi9994! It took me a while to digest your answer haha. at  first I thought I need to create a new function. Until I realize I have to put your answer in UPDATE function. Thanks again! I really appreciate it! :)